# Stack multiple p-messages

Tags: notifications, primeng

I want to stack multiple message msgs on top of one another.

I am looping over all the errors and inserting them in msg array.

component.ts

```
msgs: Message[] = [];

....
....

for (const errorName in errors) {
      if (errorName) {
        this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: summary, detail: errorName });
      }
    }
```

component.html

```
<p-messages [value]="msgs"></p-messages>
```

How can I get all the three messages stacked one below the other/ on three separate lines?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `<p-messages [value]="msgs" class="display:block;"></p-messages>`

Comment: Tried this. It applies `display: block` to the entire p-message box (i.e all the three messages combined.)

Answer (score 0):

I never used that before, but logic thing is that you loop over messages and for each print `<p>`, that way they must be separate

Answer (score 0):

Can't you add break lines between each message?  between each message